# Flutter - Create Map from two JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary

I need to create a Map dictionary for this two JSON for creating a view like App Store/Play Store so, a view with cell grouped by different heading.

First JSON

```
[
   {
      "category_id":"1",
      "language_code":"it",
      "category_name":"punti d'interesse",
      "category_description":"descrizione",
      "is_hidden":"0"
   },
   {
      "category_id":"2",
      "language_code":"it",
      "category_name":"farmacie",
      "category_description":"desc farm",
      "is_hidden":"0"
   }
]
```

Second JSON

```
[
   {
      "poi_id":"1",
      "category_id":"1",
      "language_code":"it",
      "poi_name":"chiese",
      "poi_description":"",
      "poi_image":"church.jpg"
   },
   {
      "poi_id":"2",
      "category_id":"1",
      "language_code":"it",
      "poi_name":"monumenti",
      "poi_description":"",
      "poi_image":"monument.jpg"
   },
   {
      "poi_id":"3",
      "category_id":"2",
      "language_code":"it",
      "poi_name":"musei",
      "poi_description":"",
      "poi_image":"museum.jpg"
   }
]
```

How can I create?

Comment: Could you please explain what the expected result should look like? Also in the second list, in the third map, you have some issue with the wrong character as the quotation mark. `"poi_id”:”3”,` should be `"poi_id":"3",`

Comment: @davdog00 I expect a Map<String, List> with each "category_name" as String and the "Second JSON" as List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  // Your first json
  List<Map<String, String>> map1 = [
    {
      "category_id": "1",
      "language_code": "it",
      "category_name": "punti d'interesse",
      "category_description": "descrizione",
      "is_hidden": "0"
    },
    {
      "category_id": "2",
      "language_code": "it",
      "category_name": "farmacie",
      "category_description": "desc farm",
      "is_hidden": "0"
    }
  ];
  // Your second json
  List<Map<String, String>> map2 = [
    {
      "poi_id": "1",
      "category_id": "1",
      "language_code": "it",
      "poi_name": "chiese",
      "poi_description": "",
      "poi_image": "church.jpg"
    },
    {
      "poi_id": "2",
      "category_id": "1",
      "language_code": "it",
      "poi_name": "monumenti",
      "poi_description": "",
      "poi_image": "monument.jpg"
    },
    {
      "poi_id": "3",
      "category_id": "2",
      "language_code": "it",
      "poi_name": "musei",
      "poi_description": "",
      "poi_image": "museum.jpg"
    }
  ];
  // The function that interests you (returns a map in the format you wanted)
  Map<String, List> convertData(List<Map> categories, List<Map> pois) {
    Map<String, List> result = {};
    for (var category in categories) {
      List<Map> poisOfCategory = [];
      for (var poi in pois) {
        if (category['category_id'] == poi['category_id']) {
          poisOfCategory.add(poi);
        }
      }
      result[category['category_name']] = poisOfCategory;
    }
    return result;
  }
  // Prints the map as a string
  print(json.encode(convertData(map1, map2)));
}
```

The output would be:

```json
{
   "punti d'interesse":[
      {
         "poi_id":"1",
         "category_id":"1",
         "language_code":"it",
         "poi_name":"chiese",
         "poi_description":"",
         "poi_image":"church.jpg"
      },
      {
         "poi_id":"2",
         "category_id":"1",
         "language_code":"it",
         "poi_name":"monumenti",
         "poi_description":"",
         "poi_image":"monument.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "farmacie":[
      {
         "poi_id":"3",
         "category_id":"2",
         "language_code":"it",
         "poi_name":"musei",
         "poi_description":"",
         "poi_image":"museum.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! U have saved me...